Find the sum of all the numbers greater than 10000 formed with the digits 0,2,4,6,8.
Find the sum of all the numbers greater than 10000 formed with the digits 0,2,4,6,8. (no digit being repeated
My method of doing
keeping is 0 at units(tens,or hundreds, or thousands).
No of places to be filled up=r=4 Number of digits remain to be utilised=n=4.
Hence, the number of numbers in which 0 comes at unit(or tens, hundreds or thousands).
        = 4P4 = 4!/0! = *24*
    However, out of these 24 numbers, some begin with 0.

To find the number of such numbers, let us keep 0 at the 10000 places and 2 at the unit place,
then the remaining places to be filled up r=3

No. of digits remain to be utilised =n=3

Hence, no.of numbers of 5 digits in which 2(or4 or 6 or 8) comes at unit 
(or tens, hundreds or thousands).
        = 24-6=18

also keeping 2(or 4 or 6 or 8) at 10,000 place, total ways is 24


from all this, we can say that 2 4 6 or 8 comes at units or tens hundreds or    
thousands place in 18 number of times
But 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 comes at 10000 places in 24 number of times

hence the sum of numbers at the unit place is
=[0*24 + (2+4+6+8) *18] *1

hence the sum of numbers at the tens place is
=[0*24 + (2+4+6+8) *18] *10

hence the sum of numbers at hundreds place is
=[0*24 + (2+4+6+8) *18] *100

hence the sum of numbers at thousands places is 
=[0*24 + (2+4+6+8) *18] *1000

hence the sum of numbers at ten thousand places is
=[0*24 + (2+4+6+8) *24] *10000 


adding all we will get 5199960

my doubt: there is a formula to do all these steps in a fraction of a second and it goes like this
$ (\text{sum of the digits}) \times \left( n-1 \right)! \times \left( \dfrac{10^n - 1}{9} \right)  $,  where $n$ is number of digits
proof for this formula Visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-numbers-can-formed-permutations-n-digits/
using the same the formula I am getting the answer as $5332800$
when we include zero(0) in this formula ,it doesn't work. so is there any other formula in which zero will also work... if not is there a shortcut for this question.
what if, for the same question they have given 2,4,6,0. where 0 alone we should use 2 times. i.e 0 alone can repeat 2 times. for this we can do the same thing but when we have seized 3 digits 2,4,6 and commuted all the values still what should we do about the second section? Whatt abt numbers like 20046,20264 etc
I can deal with Sum of all numbers that can be formed with permutations of n digits ,when repetition is allowed but, when it comes with zeros it becomes hard(multiple zeros)

If $p(n)$ denotes the formula then $p(5)-p(4)=5199960$ so agrees with your answer. Here $p(5)$ also adds numbers that start with $0$ but $p(4)$ equals the sum of these (illegal) numbers. So substraction is "healing".

It is better to understand the simple basis of the formula you quote rather than to memorise it.
$n$ distinct digits form a $[n\;\; columns\times n!\;\;rows]$ phalanx,
and each column repeats each digit $\dfrac{n!}{n}$ times,
thus $\;\;\dfrac{n!}{n}\times\left[\text{ sum of digits}\right]\times[10^0 + 10^1 + ...10^{n-1}]$
This is the basis of the formula you quote, thus
$20\cdot24\cdot 11111 = 5333280$
Having understood the basis of the formula, to take care of the complication the zero causes, all you have to do is to ignore the zero digit, compute for four digit numbers, and subtract it from $5333280$

tqsm now iam getting the answer
all I have to do is subtract (2061111) from 5333280 which gives me the answer  5199960

what if, for the same question they have given 2,4,6,0. where 0 alone we should use 2 times. i.e 0 alone can repeat 2 times.
for this we can do the same thing but when we have seized 3 digits 2,4,6 and commuted all the values still what should we do about the second section? Whatt abt numbers like 20046,20264 etc...

"what if, for the same question they have given 2,4,6,0. where 0 alone we should use 2 times. i.e 0 alone can repeat 2 times."  That'd be a different problem with a different formula.  I trust you can derive that.  (Moral: don't memorize formulas when you can understand them)

oh ok i got it tq

but when we are dealing with zeros I am finding it difficult to derive,
more than one zero is hard

Compute separately for numbers with one zero amd two zeroes, and add up.
